# get genre_id and audio_id from audio_genres_map from mediastore

Tags: android, mediastore

I want to retrieve whole audio_genres_map table from mediastore in one query. I have all the audio info and genre info but the missing piece is the mapping. I am able to do it in multiple queries. I want to achieve it one query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

managed to solve this using following query

```
String[] genresProjection = {
            Audio.Genres.Members.AUDIO_ID,
            Audio.Genres.Members.GENRE_ID
    };
context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/genres/all/members"), genresProjection, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or to retrieve all genres using MediaStore.Audio

```
    public Cursor getGenrecursor(Context context) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.getContentUri("external");
    String genre = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME;
    final String[] columns = { "_id", genre };
    return  cr.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: that was not the question

Comment: actually that was extremely helpful for other related issue

Answer (score 0):

and to expand your question, using the genre_id to bring back further details

```
        public Cursor getgenre_TrackCursor(Context context, long genreID) {
    final String track_id = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members._ID;
    final String track_no = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.TRACK;
    final String track_name = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.TITLE;
    final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.ARTIST;
    final String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.DURATION;
    final String album = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.ALBUM;
    final String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.COMPOSER;
    final String year = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.YEAR;
    final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.DATA;
    final ContentResolver resolve = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external",
            genreID);
    final String[] columns = { track_id, track_no, artist, track_name,
            album, duration, year };
    return resolve.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: i already have all the details. your approach will result in a lot many queries which i didn't want. i just wanted to map all the info songs with the genres i have. Anyways i solved my problem and posted the answer